# Shrinking a frame 80% without explicitly defining the CGRect

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

I'm trying to animate a button. The button will start with a height and width of 0 and expand to 100% of its intended size. It will then shrink down to 80% its size and then back up to 100% again.

Is there a way to do this without having to explicitly calculate the CGRect for each position? The problem is that when at 80% the frame is not perfectly aligned with the position of the frame at 100%. I have to manually calculate the x and y position of the frame which is time consuming since I'm doing this for a lot of buttons.

Here is what i'm currently trying to do:

```
    CGRect smallPlay = CGRectMake(PlayButton.frame.origin.x + 94, PlayButton.frame.origin.y + 23, 0, 0);
    CGRect almostFullPlay = CGRectMake(40, 170, 160, 30);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                    delay:0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                    animations:^{

                     PlayButton.frame = smallPlay;
                     PlayButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 178, 187, 45);

                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 
                         delay:0 
                         options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut 
                         animations:^{

                             PlayButton.frame = almostFullPlay;
                             PlayButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 178,187, 45);

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
                     }
                      ];
                 }];
```

Edit: I realize that I could write a function to calculate the frame at 80% but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this that would not require me to write anything extra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you just want to temporarily manipulate the button's appearance. If that's the case, instead of transforming its `frame`, try transforming its `transform`! Here's a starting point. Let me know if you need a bit more to understand.

```
[UIView
    animateWithDuration:  ...
    delay:                ...
    options:              UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
    animations:           ^ {
        PlayButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);
    }];
```

To restore the button to its original transformation (called the "identity transform"), set its `transform` property to `CGAffineTransformIdentity`.

Once you've got that figured out, read up on `CGAffineTransform` (the Quartz cousin of `NSAffineTransform`, and the 2D great uncle of `CATransform3D`.)